# Syntax error on token "getInstance", Identifier expected after this token

Tags: java, android, automation

```
private class CrashWatcher implements UiWatcher {
    public boolean checkForCondition() {
        UiObject crashButton = new UiObject(
                new UiSelector().textStartsWith("Unfortunately,"));
        if (crashButton.exists()) {
            log("Found the OK dialog");
            UiObject okButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(
                    "android.widget.Button").text("OK"));
            try {
                okButton.click();
            } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
                log("The chance of not having 'OK' button when the application crash is extremely less.");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ".", { expected
    - Syntax error on token "getInstance", Identifier expected after this token

```
UiDevice.getInstance().registerWatcher(CRASH_WATCHER_NAME, new UiWatcher());
```

Comment: The code you posted doesnt contain the code in the error. Post all your code.

Comment: If you can't see where the problem is just comment out code until it compiles. That will give you a clue where to look.